# cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue nullable int

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

In my data layer class, I initialize a parameter like so:

```
private int? _DependencyID;

public int? DependencyID
{ get {return _DependencyID;} set {_DependencyID = value;} }

public ConstructorMethod()
{
    _DependencyID = (int?)null;
}
```

In the class Insert() method, I am attempting

```
cmd.AddWithValue("@DependencyID", _DependencyID);
```

If _DependencyID has a value, all is well.
If _DependencyID is null, I get error:

> The parameterized query
>   '(@param1(nvarchar(10),
>   @param2(nvarchar(255), expects the
>   parameter '@DependecyID", which was
>   not supplied

I found this [article][1], so I tried adjusting code like so:

```
cmd.AddWithValue("@DependencyID", _DependencyID == null? DBNull.Value : _DependencyID); 

                           and
cmd.AddWithValue("@DependencyID", _DependencyID == null? (int?) DBNull.Value : _DependencyID);
```

Either way, there are issues. How should I handle this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an `object`:

```
cmd.AddWithValue("@DependencyID", _DependencyID == null? DBNull.Value : (object)_DependencyID);
```

You can shorten that to

```
cmd.AddWithValue("@DependencyID", (object)_DependencyID ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: just so I understand, is it because DBNull.Value is an object that casting _DependencyID to an object makes this work? So the cmd takes care of boxing and unboxing?

Comment: BTW, thank you everyone for your quick responses.... SLak's answer just jumped out at me and I understood it more quickly than the others. Thank you all

Comment: @Bengal: No.  You only need the cast to tell the the compiler what type the expression is.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an extension to simply the code.

```
public static class SQLExtension
{
    public static SqlParameter AddWithNullable<T>(
        this SqlParameterCollection collection, 
        string parameterName, 
        Nullable<T> value) where T : struct, IComparable
    {
        return collection.AddWithValue(
            parameterName, (value.HasValue ? value.Value : (object)DBNull.Value)
        );
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use it.

```
cmd.AddWithNullable("@DependencyID", _DependencyID);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIC, ADO.NET/SQL don't support nullable types this way.

The last example looks closest to correct to me. What kind of issues are you having with it? If you are just getting a compile error related to types, type cast your value to object:

```
(object)DependencyID.Value;
```

Since both values on either side of `:` must be of the same type.